# What are the costs of Custom B2B and Volume Purchase Program?

Tags: ios

I am looking to distribute an app to a client remotely using the custom B2B & Volume Purchase Program. However, I cannot find any information on the Apple Dev website about the cost of doing so.

How much will it cost my self and my client to remotely distribute an app using this method?

This will only be going to about 5 iPads.

Answer (score 1):

From a bird's eye view, the VPP is a "secret" App Store only available for companies (they need an D&B number, e.g.), hence the term "B2B"

- The only costs are the payment costs for the apps the customer buys
- The minimum price is 9.99$ (so there are no "free" apps allowed)
- Typically, the customer buys multiple licenses at once, gets "redemption codes" which then can be used on the single devices to download and install the app

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides a document that outlines the VPP program.

https://www.apple.com/business/docs/site/VPP_Business_Guide.pdf

> Once the developer has created an app and has identified you as the
> authorized purchaser, they can offer the app for free or set a price
> just for you.